# Whirr: Cannot connect to Hadoop cluster on EC2 after lauch-cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, apache-whirr

I am new to Whirr and I'm trying to setup a Hadoop cluster on EC2 with Whirr,I have followed the tutorial on Cloudera https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Whirr+Installation

Before install Whirr, I install Hadoop (0.20.2-cdh3u3), then install Whirr (0.5.0-cdh3u3).

Here's my cluster config file

```
whirr.cluster-name=large-cluster
whirr.instance-templates=1 hadoop-jobtracker+hadoop-namenode,1 hadoop-datanode+hadoop-tasktracker
whirr.provider=aws-ec2
whirr.identity=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
whirr.credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
whirr.private-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa
whirr.public-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
whirr.hadoop-install-function=install_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hadoop-configure-function=configure_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hardware-id=m1.large
whirr.image-id=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3
whirr.location-id=us-east-1
```

The cluster lauching looks normally

```
khiem@master ~ $ whirr launch-cluster --config large-hadoop.properties 
Bootstrapping cluster
Configuring template
Starting 1 node(s) with roles [hadoop-datanode, hadoop-tasktracker]
Configuring template
Starting 1 node(s) with roles [hadoop-jobtracker, hadoop-namenode]
Nodes started: [[id=us-east-1/i-9aa01dfd, providerId=i-9aa01dfd, group=large-cluster, name=null, location=[id=us-east-1a, scope=ZONE, description=us-east-1a, parent=us-east-1, iso3166Codes=[US-VA], metadata={}], uri=null, imageId=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3, os=[name=null, family=ubuntu, version=10.04, arch=paravirtual, is64Bit=true, description=ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-amd64-server-20101020.manifest.xml], state=RUNNING, loginPort=22, privateAddresses=[10.196.142.64], publicAddresses=[107.20.64.97], hardware=[id=m1.large, providerId=m1.large, name=null, processors=[[cores=2.0, speed=2.0]], ram=7680, volumes=[[id=null, type=LOCAL, size=10.0, device=/dev/sda1, durable=false, isBootDevice=true], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdb, durable=false, isBootDevice=false], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdc, durable=false, isBootDevice=false]], supportsImage=is64Bit()], loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={}]]
Nodes started: [[id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, providerId=i-0aa31e6d, group=large-cluster, name=null, location=[id=us-east-1a, scope=ZONE, description=us-east-1a, parent=us-east-1, iso3166Codes=[US-VA], metadata={}], uri=null, imageId=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3, os=[name=null, family=ubuntu, version=10.04, arch=paravirtual, is64Bit=true, description=ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-amd64-server-20101020.manifest.xml], state=RUNNING, loginPort=22, privateAddresses=[10.85.130.43], publicAddresses=[50.17.128.123], hardware=[id=m1.large, providerId=m1.large, name=null, processors=[[cores=2.0, speed=2.0]], ram=7680, volumes=[[id=null, type=LOCAL, size=10.0, device=/dev/sda1, durable=false, isBootDevice=true], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdb, durable=false, isBootDevice=false], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdc, durable=false, isBootDevice=false]], supportsImage=is64Bit()], loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={}]]
Authorizing firewall ingress to [Instance{roles=[hadoop-jobtracker, hadoop-namenode], publicIp=50.17.128.123, privateIp=10.85.130.43, id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, nodeMetadata=[id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, providerId=i-0aa31e6d, group=large-cluster, name=null, location=[id=us-east-1a, scope=ZONE, description=us-east-1a, parent=us-east-1, iso3166Codes=[US-VA], metadata={}], uri=null, imageId=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3, os=[name=null, family=ubuntu, version=10.04, arch=paravirtual, is64Bit=true, description=ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-amd64-server-20101020.manifest.xml], state=RUNNING, loginPort=22, privateAddresses=[10.85.130.43], publicAddresses=[50.17.128.123], hardware=[id=m1.large, providerId=m1.large, name=null, processors=[[cores=2.0, speed=2.0]], ram=7680, volumes=[[id=null, type=LOCAL, size=10.0, device=/dev/sda1, durable=false, isBootDevice=true], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdb, durable=false, isBootDevice=false], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdc, durable=false, isBootDevice=false]], supportsImage=is64Bit()], loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={}]}] on ports [50070, 50030] for [116.96.138.41/32]
Authorizing firewall ingress to [Instance{roles=[hadoop-jobtracker, hadoop-namenode], publicIp=50.17.128.123, privateIp=10.85.130.43, id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, nodeMetadata=[id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, providerId=i-0aa31e6d, group=large-cluster, name=null, location=[id=us-east-1a, scope=ZONE, description=us-east-1a, parent=us-east-1, iso3166Codes=[US-VA], metadata={}], uri=null, imageId=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3, os=[name=null, family=ubuntu, version=10.04, arch=paravirtual, is64Bit=true, description=ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-amd64-server-20101020.manifest.xml], state=RUNNING, loginPort=22, privateAddresses=[10.85.130.43], publicAddresses=[50.17.128.123], hardware=[id=m1.large, providerId=m1.large, name=null, processors=[[cores=2.0, speed=2.0]], ram=7680, volumes=[[id=null, type=LOCAL, size=10.0, device=/dev/sda1, durable=false, isBootDevice=true], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdb, durable=false, isBootDevice=false], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdc, durable=false, isBootDevice=false]], supportsImage=is64Bit()], loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={}]}] on ports [8020, 8021] for [50.17.128.123/32]
Running configuration script
Configuration script run completed
Running configuration script
Configuration script run completed
Completed configuration of large-cluster
Namenode web UI available at http://ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:50070
Jobtracker web UI available at http://ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:50030
Wrote Hadoop site file /home/khiem/.whirr/large-cluster/hadoop-site.xml
Wrote Hadoop proxy script /home/khiem/.whirr/large-cluster/hadoop-proxy.sh
Wrote instances file /home/khiem/.whirr/large-cluster/instances
Started cluster of 2 instances
Cluster{instances=[Instance{roles=[hadoop-datanode, hadoop-tasktracker], publicIp=107.20.64.97, privateIp=10.196.142.64, id=us-east-1/i-9aa01dfd, nodeMetadata=[id=us-east-1/i-9aa01dfd, providerId=i-9aa01dfd, group=large-cluster, name=null, location=[id=us-east-1a, scope=ZONE, description=us-east-1a, parent=us-east-1, iso3166Codes=[US-VA], metadata={}], uri=null, imageId=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3, os=[name=null, family=ubuntu, version=10.04, arch=paravirtual, is64Bit=true, description=ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-amd64-server-20101020.manifest.xml], state=RUNNING, loginPort=22, privateAddresses=[10.196.142.64], publicAddresses=[107.20.64.97], hardware=[id=m1.large, providerId=m1.large, name=null, processors=[[cores=2.0, speed=2.0]], ram=7680, volumes=[[id=null, type=LOCAL, size=10.0, device=/dev/sda1, durable=false, isBootDevice=true], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdb, durable=false, isBootDevice=false], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdc, durable=false, isBootDevice=false]], supportsImage=is64Bit()], loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={}]}, Instance{roles=[hadoop-jobtracker, hadoop-namenode], publicIp=50.17.128.123, privateIp=10.85.130.43, id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, nodeMetadata=[id=us-east-1/i-0aa31e6d, providerId=i-0aa31e6d, group=large-cluster, name=null, location=[id=us-east-1a, scope=ZONE, description=us-east-1a, parent=us-east-1, iso3166Codes=[US-VA], metadata={}], uri=null, imageId=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3, os=[name=null, family=ubuntu, version=10.04, arch=paravirtual, is64Bit=true, description=ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-amd64-server-20101020.manifest.xml], state=RUNNING, loginPort=22, privateAddresses=[10.85.130.43], publicAddresses=[50.17.128.123], hardware=[id=m1.large, providerId=m1.large, name=null, processors=[[cores=2.0, speed=2.0]], ram=7680, volumes=[[id=null, type=LOCAL, size=10.0, device=/dev/sda1, durable=false, isBootDevice=true], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdb, durable=false, isBootDevice=false], [id=null, type=LOCAL, size=420.0, device=/dev/sdc, durable=false, isBootDevice=false]], supportsImage=is64Bit()], loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={}]}], configuration={hadoop.job.ugi=root,root, mapred.job.tracker=ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8021, hadoop.socks.server=localhost:6666, fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=AKIAIGXAURLAB7CQE77A, fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey=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, fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=AZIAIGXIOPLAB7CQE77A, hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default=org.apache.hadoop.net.SocksSocketFactory, fs.default.name=hdfs://ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8020/, fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=dWDRq2z0EQegdPrbbL8Dab3eCu98O32r3gOrIbOK}}
```

I've also started the proxy and update the local Hadoop configuration follow Cloudera tutorial, but when I tried to test the HDFS with `hadoop fs -ls /`

the terminal prints connection error:

```
12/04/12 11:54:43 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
12/04/12 11:54:43 INFO security.UserGroupInformation: JAAS Configuration already set up for Hadoop, not re-installing.
12/04/12 11:54:45 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com/50.17.128.123:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/04/12 11:54:46 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com/50.17.128.123:8020. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/04/12 11:54:48 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com/50.17.128.123:8020. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/04/12 11:54:49 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com/50.17.128.123:8020. Already tried 3 time(s).
```

In the proxy terminal

```
Running proxy to Hadoop cluster at
ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Use Ctrl-c to quit.
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-50-17-128-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com,50.17.128.123' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. 
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused 
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused 
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

The namenode webUI (50070 port also not available), I can ssh to the namenode but inside the namenode, it looks like there's none of Hadoop or Java installation, is this strange thing?