# Whirr could not download hadoop

Tags: apache-whirr

following the example of the quickstart guide http://whirr.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/quick-start-guide.html I wanted to start a whirr hadoop cluster. Unfortunately I get the same errors as this entry here [Whirr: Cannot connect to Hadoop cluster on EC2 after lauch-cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117792/whirr-cannot-connect-to-hadoop-cluster-on-ec2-after-lauch-cluster) .
I see in the output of launching the cluster that seemingly there is already some issue when downloading hadoop. Any ideas?
Thanks!

bin/whirr launch-cluster --config ~/.whirr/hadoop.propertiesRunning on provider aws-ec2  using identity AKIAJUS7X6OK3HC3SJMQ
Bootstrapping cluster
Configuring template for bootstrap-hadoop-datanode_hadoop-tasktracker
Configuring template for bootstrap-hadoop-jobtracker_hadoop-namenode
Starting 1 node(s) with roles [hadoop-datanode, hadoop-tasktracker] 
Starting 1 node(s) with roles [hadoop-jobtracker, hadoop-namenode]

> > running InitScript{INSTANCE_NAME=bootstrap-hadoop-jobtracker_hadoop-namenode} on    node(us-east-1/i-6343df03)
> >     running InitScript{INSTANCE_NAME=bootstrap-hadoop-datanode_hadoop-tasktracker} on node(us-east-1/i-6143df01)

<< error running InitScript{INSTANCE_NAME=bootstrap-hadoop-datanode_hadoop-tasktracker} on node(us-east-1/i-6143df01): {output=This function does nothing. It just needs to exist so Statements.call("retry_helpers") doesn't call something which doesn't exist
....
....
Could not download  http://apache.osuosl.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-     1.0.4.tar.gz.md5. Continuing.
Failed to download hadoop-1.0.4.tar.gz. Aborting.
, error=dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:

Comment: the repository does not exist as since yesterday apache released version 1.2.0. But even pointing the tarball to that version doesn't solve the rest of my problems.... Thankful for any helpful advises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the tarball url would help you to install hadoop correctly.

e.g.

```
whirr.hadoop.version=1.2.1
whirr.hadoop.tarball.url=http://apache.osuosl.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-${whirr.hadoop.version}/hadoop-${whirr.hadoop.version}.tar.gz
```

The error of md5 download is because whirr uses `install_tarball.sh` in `whirr/core/src/main/resources/functions`

you can change the `HadoopClusterActionHandler.java` to use `install_tarball_no_md5.sh` in `whirr/core/src/main/resources/functions/`